# XIMEA Camera under linux?

Tags: ros, opencv, driver, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently trying to get XIMEA working with OpenCV 2.3 / 2.4 or ROS under linux, I know prosilica works and the wiki has examples.  I have the vaViewer (comes with XIMEA) working under linux, but trying to write an example to just acquire an image with OpenCV.  I know there is support built into OpenCV 2.3 for XIMEA and is built with the flag ./configure -DWITH_XIMEA=ON.  I'm just wondering if anyone has successfully gotten this to run under linux and if they could please provide me with some example code to just grab an image.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35849/ximea-camera-under-linux?/) by [xamox](https://answers.ros.org/users/2554/xamox/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2012-06-06

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is now working.  XIMEA was kind enough to help me solve the situation very quickly as well as getting a patch submitted to OpenCV (which is merged into the latest SVN and should ship with OpenCV 2.4.2).

They were also nice enough to update their wiki on how to get things working under linux:
http://www.ximea.com/support/wiki/vision-libraries/OpenCV_Installation_in_Linux

---

Originally posted by [xamox](https://answers.ros.org/users/2554/xamox/) with karma: 46 on 2012-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1